# DevTools restarts twice in Intellij

Tags: macos, spring-boot, intellij-idea, devtools

I'm starting a new Spring Boot 2.4.2 application in Intellij and have DevTools added.
The Spring Boot is created in spring.io's homepage and not through Intellij.
In Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler, I have checked: Build project automatically.
Then I search for Registry... in Help -> Find Actions and search for:         compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running, and checked that too.

I start the Spring application as normal, and it starts in 4 seconds.
I have some output-text in the Main-class and save that file, but it runs Spring Boot twice.
First it runs Spring Boot and then shuts it down and then runs it again.

> Thread-19] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down
> ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'           Thread-19]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> Thread-19] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477:
> Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory
> shut-down'            Thread-19] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter
> : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name
> 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor':
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is
> already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add
> ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200] Thread-19]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-4 - Shutdown
> initiated...       Thread-19] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
> : HikariPool-4 - Shutdown completed.

After this it start the Spring Boot application again.
First it starts it up in 1.0 seconds and then shuts it down to restart it again and second time it goes up in 0.6 seconds, but I don't get why it runs the Spring application twice when i saved it once.

I'm on a Mac-Catalina and running Intellij 2020.3.1 and Spring Boot 2.4.2

Answer (score 6):

See here
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25269

Which suggests increasing the quiet period

```
spring.devtools.restart.quiet-period=900
```

Which stopped the double load for me

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thank you very much. I added these values:
spring.devtools.restart.quiet-period: 2000 spring.devtools.restart.poll-interval: 3000